# Calling a Method not Associated with a class inside class a PHP

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to use the PHP method time() within a class. I'm a little lost on how to call it since PHP thinks the time method is part of the class it's in.

Code

```
Class FingerPrint
{
     protected $time;

     public function __construct()
     {
          $this->time = time();
     }
}
```

Comment: `\time()` [global namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php)

Comment: You learn something everyday! @cske Thanks! You should put it in as an answer so I can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to prefix global function call with `\`

```
\time()
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php

> Without any namespace definition, all class and function definitions
>   are placed into the global space - as it was in PHP before namespaces
>   were supported. Prefixing a name with \ will specify that the name is
>   required from the global space even in the context of the namespace.